# JPA managed entity not saving as expected

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

based on this article https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-save-saveandflush-and-saveall/ I understand that calling a save for a managed entity is waste or resources and not actually required, and I tried this in my local and it works as expected. e.g:

```java
@Override
@Transactional
public UserEntity update(User user){
UserEntity e = userRepo.findById(user.getId());
e.setName("test");
return e;
}
```

without calling the `save` method the update query is called.

but when I call it from an inner method ,i.e

```java
@Override
public UserEntity update(User user){
return performUpdate(user);
}

@Transactional
public UserEntity performUpdate(User user){
UserEntity e = userRepo.findById(user.getId());
e.setName("test");
return e;
}
```

Now for some reason the update query is not being called at all, can someone explain me why this is happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: Many Java annotations, including Transactional, require a proxy to be setup on the method. This requires that the method is called from another class.